# Unable to Apply Segmentation Mask to Images using Hugging Face's HRNet

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, image-segmentation, torchvision

I am trying to detect objects with Hugging Face's pre-trained hrnet within two different sets of objects (`lrg` and `sml` images). These images have already been properly partitioned to their buckets `image_paths_x` (not included in this code snippet). I am able to return (print) the predicted class index, however I am unable to apply the segmentation mask to the image.

The code is as follows:

```
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from PIL import Image

# Load the hrnet_w18 model
model = timm.create_model('hrnet_w18', pretrained=True)

# Classify the "lrg" images
for i in range(10):
    # Download the image to a local file
    image_file = f'/content/{image_paths_lrg[i].split("/")[-1]}'
    blob = bucket.blob(image_paths_lrg[i])
    blob.download_to_filename(image_file)

    # Load the image and apply any necessary preprocessing
    img = Image.open(image_file).convert('L')  # convert image to grayscale
    img_rgb = Image.new('RGB', img.size)
    img_rgb.paste(img)
    img_tensor = ToTensor()(img_rgb).unsqueeze(0)

    # Make a prediction using the model
    with torch.no_grad():
        model.eval()
        output = model(img_tensor)

    # Get the predicted class index
    predicted_class_index = torch.argmax(output)

    # Print the prediction result
    print('Image path:', image_paths_lrg[i])
    print('Predicted class index:', predicted_class_index.item())

    # Perform segmentation using the predicted class index
    segmentation_mask = (output.argmax(dim=1) == predicted_class_index).squeeze().numpy()

    # Convert the grayscale image to 3-channel format
    img_rgb = np.array(img_rgb)

    # Reshape the segmentation mask to match the shape of the RGB image
    segmentation_mask_reshaped = np.expand_dims(segmentation_mask, axis=2)

    # Resize the segmentation mask to match the shape of the RGB image
    segmentation_mask_resized = np.repeat(segmentation_mask_reshaped, 3, axis=2)

    # Apply the segmentation mask to the image
    segmented_image = img_rgb * segmentation_mask_resized

    # Display the segmented image
    plt.imshow(segmented_image)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

# Classify the "sml" images
for i in range(10):
    # Download the image to a local file
    image_file = f'/content/{image_paths_sml[i].split("/")[-1]}'
    blob = bucket.blob(image_paths_sml[i])
    blob.download_to_filename(image_file)

    # Load the image and apply any necessary preprocessing
    img = Image.open(image_file).convert('L')  # convert image to grayscale
    img_rgb = Image.new('RGB', img.size)
    img_rgb.paste(img)
    img_tensor = ToTensor()(img_rgb).unsqueeze(0)

    # Make a prediction using the model
    with torch.no_grad():
        model.eval()
        output = model(img_tensor)

    # Get the predicted class index
    predicted_class_index = torch.argmax(output)

    # Print the prediction result
    print('Image path:', image_paths_sml[i])
    print('Predicted class index:', predicted_class_index.item())

    # Perform segmentation using the predicted class index
    segmentation_mask = (output.argmax(dim=1) == predicted_class_index).squeeze().numpy()

    # Convert the grayscale image to 3-channel format
    img_rgb = np.array(img_rgb)

    # Reshape the segmentation mask to match the shape of the RGB image
    segmentation_mask_reshaped = np.expand_dims(segmentation_mask, axis=2)

    # Resize the segmentation mask to match the shape of the RGB image
    segmentation_mask_resized = np.repeat(segmentation_mask_reshaped, 3, axis=2)

    # Apply the segmentation mask to the image
    segmented_image = img_rgb * segmentation_mask_resized

    # Display the segmented image
    plt.imshow(segmented_image)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

And the respective error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b45eeaadc21e> in <cell line: 8>()
     37 
     38     # Apply the segmentation mask to the image
---> 39     segmented_image = img_rgb * np.expand_dims(segmentation_mask, axis=2)
     40 
     41     # Display the segmented image

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1389             pass
   1390     # Going via an iterator directly is slower than via list comprehension.
-> 1391     axis = tuple([normalize_axis_index(ax, ndim, argname) for ax in axis])
   1392     if not allow_duplicate and len(set(axis)) != len(axis):
   1393         if argname:

AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Do I need to reshape the segmentation_mask array to have a shape of (e.g. the height, width, 1) before resizing it to match the shape of the RGB image? Or is there additional reshaping I could do to allow me to plot this segmented image? Thanks in advance!

Comment: debug the program. inspect `segmentation_mask`. inspect the calculation of `segmentation_mask`.